# Is the emptiness of intersection of two CFLs decidable?

Tags: context-free, undecidability

Consider $L = \{\langle L_1, L_2\rangle\mid L_1, L_2 \in \text{CFL} \text{ and } L_1 \cap L_2 = \emptyset \}$. How to prove that $L \notin R $?

$L_1, L_2$ encoded in chomsky-normal-form.

Comment: How would you encode a language?

Comment: @nirshahar, Why does it matter? PDA, CNF, CNF are equivalent...

Comment: @Yanirmr right now the question is not well defined. If you decide to use either a PDA or a CFG - it will become well defined.
Just pointing this out :)